# A simple static file location issue

Tags: django

I've gone and adjusted something somewhere along the line, and cant find way back.

My file structure

```
examplesite1

    --registration
        --A bunch of files well ignore
    --snapboard
        --static
             --Associated static folders css, js etc           
        --templates
            --snapboard
                --html files
                --some folders    
    --manage.py
    --settings.py
    --urls.py
    --__init__.py
```

Im having trouble pointing the html files in templates/snapboard to the static files in snapboard/media.The code in the html is

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ SNAP_MEDIA_PREFIX }}/css/yui/reset-fonts-grids.css" />
```

in the settings file I have of that which i think is valid

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = '/snapboard/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (

 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
 #'django.template.loaders.eggs.load_template_source',

)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (

)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (

 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 # 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',

)

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "snapboard.views.snapboard_default_context",

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
    'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
    'snapboard.middleware.threadlocals.ThreadLocals',
    'snapboard.middleware.ban.IPBanMiddleware',
    'snapboard.middleware.ban.UserBanMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'examplesite1.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

)

INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'examplesite1',
    'registration',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.markup',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'snapboard',
    'pagination',

)

SNAP_MEDIA_PREFIX = MEDIA_URL + 'static/'

# Set MEDIA_ROOT so the project works out of the box

import os

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'snapboard/media')
```

Ive spent bloody ages going through a process of elimination trying a ton different combinations with out success. Whats the correct way to code this.

Comment: Are you using the development server? What version of Django are you running?

Comment: Im running django1.3 I had it working and all looking good. Then i did something and now, all though it works, its not styled and formatted properly. If for example i get rid of all <scripts> and <link> on the html page, it makes no difference, telling me it's a static file problem. Sorry though i didnt mention that it still actually works.

Answer (score 0):

make ur media url as `MEDIA_URL = '/snapboard/'` and  in your code change `href="{{ SNAP_MEDIA_PREFIX }}/css/yui/reset-fonts-grids.css"` to `href="{{ SNAP_MEDIA_PREFIX }}css/yui/reset-fonts-grids.css"`  because `{{ SNAP_MEDIA_PREFIX }}/css/` is not same as `{{ SNAP_MEDIA_PREFIX }}css/`

Comment: Nope. Didn't do anything. But i do see what you mean about the /. Chur

Answer (score 0):

What version of Django are you running? If it's 1.3+, you should be using the staticfiles contrib package and you app's "media" directory should be named `static` to allow Django to pick it up.

Otherwise, there's no support for static resources inside your apps, so you need to copy all those files into your `MEDIA_ROOT` directory.

**UPDATED**

Drop the whole `SNAP_MEDIA_PREFIX` business; it's unnecessary and complicating things. This is all you need:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media')
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
```

Never *directly* use `STATIC_ROOT`. This is the directory where the `collectstatic` management command will dump files, and should be served directly by your production webserver. Django *never* serves anything from here.

`MEDIA_ROOT` is for uploads, now, i.e. any time you have a `FileField`, `ImageField`, etc. on a model, the actual file will be put somewhere in here. It also should be directly served by your webserver in production. Don't put any of your static resources here.

*Do* put all of your static resources in your app's `static` directory. Each app's `static` directory *will* be served by Django in development under `STATIC_URL`. So, `<project_root>/some_app/static/style.css` will be available at `/static/style.css` through your browser. Because of this, it's usually a good idea to namespace your static directories, i.e. use `<project_root>/some_app/static/some_app/style.css` instead so that the URL becomes `/static/some_app/style.css`. That way your static files don't overwrite each other.

If you need project-wide static resources, create an entirely different directory in your project (I tend to use `assets`) and then add that to `STATICFILES_DIRS` like so:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'assets'),
)
```

Comment: runnind django 1.3. I did what you siad but no change. Have updated my settings files to meet current changes suggested in this thread. Don't suppose you could have a look